# node js - ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

what I want is to register my service worker in my progressive web app. I created my sw.js file and in my app.js file I wanted to do this:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/sw.js')
        .then(function(){
            console.log('Service worker registered!');
        });

}
```

but this is the error that I am receiving: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined.

What should I do?

I expected it to work, but it is not working.

Comment: `ServiceWorker` is a browser API, not something in node.js. You don't use it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

A service worker is a script that runs independently in the browser background , not server side.

For using ServiceWorker in node.js use [node-service-worker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-service-worker)